# Error display font when a pdf is reading in icepdf

Tags: java, swing, pdf, fonts, icepdf

Good morning

I use icepdf 7.1.4 but the fonts are displayed incorrectly on one of my documents
this document has the font ArialMT.ttf, Arial-BoldMT.ttf, Helvetica.ttf, Helvetica-Bold.ttf, Helvetica-Oblique.ttf and Helvetica-BoldOblique.ttf, and it displays well if I open it with the windows pdf reader

i have use the FontPropertiesManager.getInstance().loadOrReadSystemFonts() method; but it doesn't work

We must copy the fonts to c:/windows/Font (for me it's ttf) isn't it ? but even doing this it doesn't work.
what I would have liked is to be able to load the font for icepdf from ttf files on the hard drive.

Thanks for your help

Sincerely

i have tried the FontPropertiesManager.getInstance().loadOrReadSystemFonts() method
i have tried several version of ice pdf
i have tried the readSystemFonts, readFontPackage methods

Comment: always start by checking the documentation of the toolset itself: https://www.icesoft.org/wiki/display/PDF/Adding+Font+Paths+to+the+FontManager

Comment: Yes we have done this method,we also tried the following methods: readSystemFonts, readFontPackage, readFonts, FontPropertiesManager.getInstance().loadOrReadSystemFonts();

Comment: I will add that if I use readSystemFonts on my fonts I get this error 

org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser parse
AVERTISSEMENT: Skip table '' which goes past the file size; offset: 1146308935, size: 8580, font size: 13674828
févr. 13, 2024 10:48:42 AM org.icepdf.core.pobjects.fonts.zfont.fontFiles.ZFontTrueType <init>
AVERTISSEMENT: Error reading font file with
java.io.IOException: 'head' table is mandatory
 at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parseTables(TTFParser.java:198)
 at org.apache.fontbox.ttf.TTFParser.parse(TTFParser.java:165)

Comment: The fontbox error messages can usually be ignored as there is pretty noisy logging in that library and there is fall back code.  Can you create an issue at https://github.com/pcorless/icepdf/issues and post a sample file?  Release 7.2.0 is close to going out the door, it would be nice ot address any issue introduced in 7.1.4.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, these are medical files produced by laboratories I cannot send them an exemple to you, i have create an issue here https://github.com/pcorless/icepdf/issues/340 

Best regards